# I want to set a value inside xpath to x /// tr[x]

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I want to set the value inside the XPath before was:

```
.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""portal""]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]", 5)
```

Can someone advise me what I can do to make its work?
I want to change to something like below and set the value of x or y = integer to change the XPath.

```
.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""portal""]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[x]/td[y]", 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just concatenate them in:

```
.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""portal""]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/" & _ 
       "div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[" & x & "]/td[" & y & "]", 5)
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply but it's give me error like this "runtime error 32 application defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Oh It's work now , Thanks again and sorry about my english :)